# Записать в list все константы, которые есть в math (Python)

Tags: python

```
math_functions = [getattr(math, attr) for attr in dir(math) if callable(getattr(math, attr))]
```

Так я получаю все функции, имеющиеся в модуле math, а как получить все константы?

Comment: Если нужно только math, то там всего две константы - е и пи.

Comment: @Эникейщик, `e, tau, pi` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#constants, мы можем считать `math.nan` и `math.inf` за константы?)

Comment: @Эникейщик нет)

Comment: @entithat Ай, точно :) Мне ссылка на вторую версию открылась

Comment: В `python` понятие константы отсутствует. с помощью определенных ухищрений можно запретить менять некоторые поля, но сделать `main.pi = 0` никто не запретит. Можете считать константой все, что не `callable` например, и не начинается с `'__'`, но это тоже шаткий путь. К слову, все классы тоже `callable` и все экземпляры реализующие `__call__` тоже.

Comment: Можно так попробовать: https://pastebin.com/NaRB6ykQ. `vars()` возвращает `__dict__` атрибут объекта, проходимся по каждому, проверяем тип каждого значения ключа (встроенная это функция или нет. И так же проверяем на наличие `_`, чтобы отфильтрировать такие атрибуты, как `__name__`, `__doc__` и т.д.)